# Using pg_notify in PostgreSQL trigger function

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, notifications, plpgsql

I am attempting to issue a notification from a PostgreSQL trigger function. I can successfully use the NOTIFY command, but I am not having any luck with pg_notify. Even though I receive a notification when I invoke the pg_notify function from the psql console, I never receive a notification when invoking the same from my trigger function.

**This version of my trigger function works as expected.** I have a Java program that is LISTENing to 'mymessage', and it receives a notification with a 'fired by NOTIFY' payload.

```
-- Function: conversation_notify()

-- DROP FUNCTION conversation_notify();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conversation_notify()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        --SELECT pg_notify('mymessage', 'fired by FUNCTION');
        NOTIFY mymessage, 'fired by NOTIFY';
        RETURN NULL;
    END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION conversation_notify() OWNER TO postgres;
```

**This version of my trigger function DOES NOT work as expected.** The only changes are uncommenting the pg_notify line and commenting out the NOTIFY line below. (I did not modify the Java application that is LISTENing.) I expect that my application LISTENing to 'mymessage' should receive a notification with a 'fired by FUNCTION' payload. The actual behavior is that nothing is received, even 30+ seconds after the corresponding table is modified.

```
-- Function: conversation_notify()

-- DROP FUNCTION conversation_notify();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conversation_notify()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        SELECT pg_notify('mymessage', 'fired by FUNCTION');
        --NOTIFY mymessage, 'fired by NOTIFY';
        RETURN NULL;
    END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION conversation_notify() OWNER TO postgres;
```

**However, I'm *really* confused, because the same pg_notify command works as expected from the psql console!** When I execute the following command, my Java application receives a notification with a 'fired by CONSOLE' payload:

```
select pg_notify('mymessage', 'fired by CONSOLE');
```

For completeness, here is my trigger definition:

```
-- Trigger: conversation_notify on ofconversation

-- DROP TRIGGER conversation_notify ON ofconversation;

CREATE TRIGGER conversation_notify
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON ofconversation
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE conversation_notify();
```

I'm trying to use pg_notify because I would like to have a dynamic payload. Right now, that's a moot point. :) The Postgres 9.0 manual indicates that this should be possible. [The NOTIFY docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html) for the 'payload' parameter state:

> (If binary data or large amounts of information need to be communicated, it's best to put it in a database table and send the key of the record.)

I've also referenced a related Stack Overflow question, and I think I've dodged this issue: [LISTEN/NOTIFY using pg_notify(text, text) in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173323/listen-notify-using-pg-notifytext-text-in-postgresql).

The database version is:

> PostgreSQL 9.0.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit

My OS is Windows XP Professional, Version 2002, SP3.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added my Java listener code below. It's based on this sample from the PostgreSQL docs: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/listennotify.html.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.postgresql.PGConnection;
import org.postgresql.PGNotification;

public class ConversationListener extends Thread
{   
    private Connection conn;
    private PGConnection pgConn;

    public ConversationListener(Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.pgConn = (PGConnection) conn;
        Statement listenStatement = conn.createStatement();
        listenStatement.execute("LISTEN mymessage");
        listenStatement.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // issue a dummy query to contact the backend
                // and receive any pending notifications.
                Statement selectStatement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
                rs.close();
                selectStatement.close();

                PGNotification notifications[] = pgConn.getNotifications();

                if (notifications != null)
                {
                    for (PGNotification pgNotification : notifications)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Got notification: " + pgNotification.getName() +
                            " with payload: " + pgNotification.getParameter());
                    }
                }

                // wait a while before checking again
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlException)
            {
                sqlException.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple Java 1.6 SE desktop application, so I'm managing my own JDBC connection and everything. I'm loading the driver via

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

I'm using the postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar library (only one on my classpath), and JDK 1.6.0_22.

Just to recap from above, the Java code works fine with NOTIFY from psql and the trigger, and with pg_notify from psql.

Comment: So what does your Java LISTEN command look like?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I updated my post with the full source of the Java class. 

The exact LISTEN command is `listenStatement.execute("LISTEN mymessage");`

Comment: if I use `NOTIFY mymessage, 'fired by NOTIFY';` how can I pass the parameter 'fired by notify'  using with JDBC it throws error.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting a similar issue, where notifications from a trigger within a transaction don't arrive when the transaction is committed.  They do all appear instantly if I issue another "LISTEN" command in the listener.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This might be to late to help but perhaps someone else will be able to use it. 
Using SELECT pg_notify('', ''); in the trigger causes the DB to respond with

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Changing the SELECT to PERFORM as the error say helps to resolve this issue and the notification gets delivered as expected. Perhaps this could have been the problem.

I have the same setup, and had the same problem.

Answer (score 15):

It might be useful to someone out there. Sometimes you want to pass whole row to "observer" and then it might be a nice idea to serialise whole row into JSON. You can achieve this with help of [row_to_json](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

```
-- Notify when record was inserted into 'prices' table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_pricesinserted()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify(
    CAST('pricesinserted' AS text),
    row_to_json(NEW)::text);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER notify_pricesinserted
  AFTER INSERT ON prices
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_pricesinserted();
```

Comment: Why `CAST('pricesinserted' AS text)` when just `'pricesinserted'` also works? (for me).

Comment: @KjetilS. maybe because of pg versions. He answered in 2015.

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notifyshipment() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify(CAST('snc' AS text),CAST(NEW.id AS text)|| ' ' || CAST(NEW.tracking_number AS text));
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER shipmentnotify AFTER UPDATE ON shipments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notifyshipment();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code directly into your create trigger function:

```
EXECUTE 'NOTIFY your_declared_notify';
```

OR

```
 PERFORM pg_notify(CAST('your_declared_notify' AS text), CAST(NEW.nameAS text));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these help with your problem, but some gotcha's I've hit are:

- You have to commit the transaction with the `LISTEN` command. I'm not familiar with Java, I don't know if you're in autocommit mode or not.
- Notifies are dispatched when you commit. I suppose for whatever reason, it could be that the transaction that triggered calling `pg_notify` did not commit or was rolled back?
- Maybe the LISTEN connection is connecting to another database than the one where NOTIFY is sent? :)

However, none of these can explain why NOTIFY works and pg_notify didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll like following syntax:

```
RAISE notice 'hstore %, patrm %, dt %, v% ', new_g, _param_id, _dt, new.v ;
```